# jQuery select child node (hidden field) within table cell

Tags: jquery, class, hidden

I am trying to refactor my code and on class click I want to access hidden value of div contained inside the class. See code below:

```
<tr>
    <td>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.EnquirerDetailsPopup, "Enquirer Details Popup")</td>
    <td class="btnSettingsToggle" style="text-align: right; padding-left: 10px;">
        <div style="float: right;" id="btnEnquirerDetailsPopup">
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.AutoWorkflowOfEnquiry, new { id = "hdnEnquirerDetailsPopup" })
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>


 $('.btnSettingsToggle').click(function () {
     // Get hidden value that's inside this click     
  });
```

I have ten of these table rows so I want to use a few lines of javaScript to get hidden field value within class of btnSettingsToggle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your jQuery needs to look more like this:

```
$(".btnSettingsToggle").on("click", function(){
    $hiddenValue = $(this).find("input[type=hidden]").val();

    alert($hiddenValue);
});
```

But better, would be to put this into a function of its own, so that the jquery is simplified to

```
 $(".btnSettingsToggle").on("click", getHiddenValue);
```

**EDIT:**

So, for completeness:

```
function getHiddenValue()
{
    $hiddenValue = $(this).find("input[type=hidden]").val();
    alert($hiddenValue);  
}

$(".btnSettingsToggle").on("click", getHiddenValue);
```

**EDIT:**

This solution does not use the ID, which would be quicker, because 10 rows were mentioned.
I've made an assumption that the ID will be unknown.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for. I'm sure I typed something similar to your answer in my code before but anyway this is perfect.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

```
$('.btnSettingsToggle').click(function () {
 // Get hidden value that's inside this click
 var hiddenValue = $(this).find('#hdnEnquirerDetailsPopup').val();
});
```

Comment: I should of explained that I don't want to hardcode the ID. Because the 9 other table rows will have a different ID.